# Javascript nested loops with setTimeout

Tags: javascript

This is a follow-up question to: [How to suspend JavaScript to allow render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544976/how-to-suspend-javascript-to-allow-render/16545110)

I wrote a function that does a kind of suspended for-loop (to allow rendering in between):

```
function loop(count, callback){
    var counter = 0
    var iteration = function(){
        callback(counter)
        counter ++;
        if (counter < count){
            setTimeout(iteration, 0)
        }
    }
    iteration();
}
```

This works nicely, using e.g. `loop(100, function(i){ console.log(i) } )`. And allows the browser to render in between each iteration.

However, problems occur when executing stuff *after* the loop, since there is no guarantee that the loop has finished. Actually, I'm thinking there is a guarantee that it has **not** (since the main thread continues after setTimeout has been called the first time). This is exacerbated when nesting these kind of loops:

```
loop(10, function(i){
    loop(10, function(j){
        console.log(i + '-' + j)
    })
})
/// This definitely does not output the numbers in order...
```

My use case is that I am running a number of simulations, each consisting of a number of steps, and I want to render in between each. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: You could take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963590/how-to-synch-javascript-callbacks/15964626#15964626), which also discusses synchronizing asynchronous code.

Comment: If you want to execute something after loop, use something like `function loop(count,callback,callback_finish){if(counter<count){}else{callback_finish()}}`.

Comment: _"and I want to render in between each"_ Why is that necessary with a timeout of 0?

Comment: Well, in my (limited) understanding, setting a timeout of 0 returns control to the browser thread, allowing it to do such stuff as redraw the DOM. Then, because the timeout is 0, as soon as possible, execution of the simulation will resume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

Edit: Updated answer after reading OP's comment below:

```
function loop(count, callback, done) {
    var counter = 0;
    var next = function () {
        setTimeout(iteration, 0);
    };
    var iteration = function () {
        if (counter < count) {
            callback(counter, next);
        } else {
            done && done();
        }
        counter++;
    }
    iteration();
}

loop(100, function (i, next) {
    console.log(i);
    next();
})


loop(10, function (i, nextI) {
    loop(10, function (j, nextJ) {
        console.log(i + '-' + j);
        nextJ();
    }, nextI);
});
```

Output:

```
1
1-1
2
1-2
3
1-3
4
1-4
5
1-5
6
1-6
7
1-7
8
1-8
9
1-9
10
11
2-1 
<< ... >>
97
98
99
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Rw2H/1/

The `loop` function can have a third argument `done` which will be run after the loop is complete, if present. The callback will have a second argument `next`, which needs to be called when you want to run the next iteration.

This way, you can call an async function inside the loop, and still let it run in order.

Comment: Looks good, though it is kind of hard to grasp. But if I copy this literally I'll lose the 'suspend' functionality inside `loop`, no? The goal of the `loop` function was to make a suspended-loop one-liner.

Comment: @Noio, I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by `'suspend' functionality`? I think the functionality is probably identical to the code you posted in your question.

Comment: The purpose of my original loop function was to call each next iteration with `setTimeout(0)` to allow the browser to render the DOM. So your function is identical probably only if I call `setTimeout(nextJ,0)`?

Comment: You are increasing the counter before comparing it! Try `loop(1, console.log)` :-/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work properly:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4Rw2H/3/)

```
var log = function (i) { console.log(i) },
    loop = function (count, callback) {
        callback(count);
        count--;
        count > 0 && arguments.callee(count, callback);
    }

loop(10, log);
console.log('end');
loop(5, log);
```